# request for member `push_back' in `num', which is of non-class type `int[((unsigned int)((int)n))]'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
std::vector<float> num;

float mean (float num[], float n)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    sum=sum+num[i];
    return (sum/n);

}
int main()  
{

    int minusElements;  
    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of Elements:";  
    cin >> n;



    minusElements = n - 1  ;
    int i,j;  
    float  temp;

    float f;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
    {
    cin >> f;
    num.push_back(f);
    }


    cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers:\n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
    cin >> num[i];
    cin.get();
    float m = mean(&num[0], num.size());


    //if num is float[n] or float* (num of elements = n)
    float mean = std::accumulate(num, num + n, 0) / n;
    cout<<mean;
}  
//46 no match for 'operator+' in 'num + n'
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to `push back` an array! Not a good idea. Something like that won't compile, use a `std::vector` or similar.

Comment: Sorry to say but your code is a horrible mess and has got worse since you've tried to follow the well intentioned advice earlier. I would throw this code away. Then decide what you are trying to learn, the first big choice is whether you are trying to learn about arrays or std::vector, and then **stick to it**. You will get absolutely nowhere by randomly chucking in bits of code you don't properly understand. Start slowly and take baby steps.

Comment: You will get advice that is good advice in general but doesn't necessarily appreciate where you're at. For instance earlier you we're advised to use std::accumulate, and you've taken that advice. There's nothing wrong with std::accumulate, but if your purpose was to learn how to write a for loop, or how to write and call your own function, then it was not the right thing to use.

Comment: @John - Changing the code in the question to make the problem go away is really not nice to us coming here later!

Answer (score 3):

`push_back` is generally called on a [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), not an array like `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a regular C-style array instead of a `std::vector` and the compiler is complaining.

`num` should be declared as

```
std::vector<int> num;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear from the error message: `num` is not an instance of a class so you can't call methods on it.  Why do you think you can call `push_back` on it?  Where do you think `push_back` is defined?

Comment: Even newbies should be able to explain the code that they wrote.  You could have said "I saw `push_back` in some example code and didn't realize there were any restrictions on where I could use it."

Answer (score 0):

`num` is not an `std::vector`, so you can't call the `push_back` method for it.

Maybe you intended to define `num` like this :

```
std::vector<int> num;
```

Note that you'd have to modify the rest of the code accordingly of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,j, num[n];
```

-->

```
int i,j;
std::vector<int> num;
```

Since when asking questions could be replaced by code? Say something buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Decide how you want to store your numbers, in either a vector or an array, and then use the operations that are available accordingly.

It seems that you edited heavily the question, as in the opening title the compiler is complaining when you try to perform an operation of a vector in `num` as `num` in that version is an array. Then the current code has the opposite problem: `num` is defined as a vector and you are trying to apply an operation that is not available in vectors but rather to pointers.

The second error can be fixed by changing the call to `std::accumulate` to use iterators:

```
float mean = std::accumulate(num.begin(), num.end(), 0) / n;
```

**NOTE**: It is a really bad idea to edit the question so that existing answers no longer make sense. You are new to StackOverflow, but expect your questions to be closed if you continue with this pattern.